# On i3 wm, gnome-terminal randomly loses transparency and starts showing cursor traces

Tags: gnome-terminal, i3-wm, transparency

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 with i3. I have reduced my terminals opacity a bit so the wallpaper is a bit visible through it. Sometimes, seemingly randomly (or at least I haven't figured out what is triggering it) it loses its transparency. The cursor also shows faint traces in its previous position as I type, and when its blinking. This goes away when I restart it, and any new terminal I open parallelly is also fine. Why is this happening and how do I stop it?